# Install the UNIX 'spell' utility on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, unix

Is there any way to install the UNIX `spell` utility on Mac OS X? It isn't installable via MacPorts nor Homebrew. Is there somewhere where the binary its self can be downloaded or some similar solution?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want `aspell`?

Comment: @DanielBeck: I am trying to use the [spell.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/spell.vim) vim plugin and it won't work with `aspell` (as far as I can see, it doesn't.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Fink, instead of MacPorts and I see spell listed in the packages, but I haven't used it before. It says that is a GNU wrapper for ispell. Is that what you are looking for?